# Is it possible to change the hostname of AWS SSH command?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh

By default AWS EC2 instances are accessible using something like this

```
ssh -i "key.pem" ubuntu@ec2-00-00-00-00.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com
```

Is it possible to change that to something along the lines of:

```
ssh -i "key.pem" ubuntu@ec2-00-00-00-00.myowndomain.com
```

Sorry if this is a noob question, I just can't figure out what to even Google. I either get tutorial about SSHing in or tutorial about running websites on an EC2 - neither helpful.

Comment: Yes if you own a domain you can point a DNS record to the EC2 server and then use that name to connect over SSH.

Comment: Is this just to simplify typing (prefer copy/paste) or for some other reason?

Comment: You'll need to know where DNS is hosted for your domain and be able to update it.  Do you have that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have your own domain name, then:

- Assign an **Elastic IP address** to the instance, which is a static IP address (it won't change if the instance is stopped and started)
- In your **DNS system** that controls your Domain Name, create a `CNAME` record for the subdomain (eg `app.mydomain.com`) that points to the Elastic IP address

Answer (score 0):

As long as both `ec2-00-00-00-00.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com` and `ec2-00-00-00-00.myowndomain.com` resolve to the same IP, you will have no accessibility issue with the underlying instance.